# Get the product price in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

I'm trying to get price without currency in a function I made.

```
function add_price_widget()
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID());
    $thePrice = $product->get_price_html();

    echo thePrice;
}
```

Displays: `100kr`

How do I get it to just give me the price `100`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What @Syntax_Error had said is correct you have to use
>   [`get_price()`](http://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productget_price/), WooCOmmerce also provide a wrapper function
>   [`wc_get_product()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_product.html) for `WC_Product` class.

So your function would look something like this:

```
function add_price_widget()
{
    $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
    $thePrice = $product->get_price(); //will give raw price
    echo $thePrice;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: woocommerce 4.5.1 - this has issues

Comment: Hi @AshwaniShukla: I just checked with WooCommerce 4.5.1, and I did not got any error. Can you please specify the issue that you are getting.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\Overrides\Order::get_price()

Comment: @AshwaniShukla: I think the issue you are getting is for some other reason, if you check this link https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-product.php#L266 `get_price()` method exists.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the function `get_price` that returns only the number (without dots or symbol)

```
function add_price_widget() {
 global $woocommerce;
 $product = new WC_Product(get_the_ID()); 
 $thePrice = $product->get_price();
 echo thePrice;
}
```

I just tested it in my site and it work. So it should work for you too.